# Existe algun paquete de ROS para progamar con bloques del estilo a Simulink?

Tags: ros, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para controlar un robot y para mandarle las instruciones al robot utilizo un nodo a modo de cliente en el que escribo las instruciones para mandarlas a otro nodo servidor a traves de un servicio, y este nodo es el que conecta al robot.
Lo que quiero es poder mandarles las instruciones a traves de una pantalla grafica del estilo a simulink en donde pueda crear bloques donde por ejemplo meter un boton de avanza, y que este se pueda comunicar con el nodo del cliente. No quiero nada de simulación solo una intefaz grafica donde poder enviar instruciones a mi robot pero sin tener que escribir instrucion a instrucion.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213287/existe-algun-paquete-de-ros-para-progamar-con-bloques-del-estilo-a-simulink?/) by [angelastras](https://answers.ros.org/users/23118/angelastras/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-07-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-07-09**:
No sé si eso que pides existe, diria que no. Sé que se existe una conexión de Matlab para ROS pero no sé si para simulink valdrá. Siempre puedes hacer un nodo de teleoperación para hacer todo más fácil.En cualquier caso, te recomiendo que escribas en inglés dado que es el idioma oficial de la página

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-05-09**:
@Javier V. Gómez is right: please use English when posting here. ROS Answers is an international support forum, where we only accept/use English.

I appreciate @mag.rod and @S.Prieto helping here, but it's not a good idea to facilitate posters using other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Como bien dice Javi V., existe una integración entre ROS y MatLab a través de su última distribución, la R2015a. Quizá desde ahí puedas enviar las órdenes que deseas y generarte una interfaz gráfica desde MatLab. Sino, siempre puedes crear tu propia interfaz gráfica en C o C++ encargada de publicar los comandos necesarios para enviar tus órdenes al robot, dependiendo del nivel de programación que poseas.

Un saludo.

---

Originally posted by [S.Prieto](https://answers.ros.org/users/23156/s.prieto/) with karma: 258 on 2015-07-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0